# Packages installed via Pip do not get imported in Python VSCode [Windows 10]

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pip

Trying to install new packages via pip on Windows, but after it installs - Python cannot resolve the import. For Example, I have just installed the Python package `similaritymeasures` and pip correctly installed it, but when I import it into my Python program, it cannot find the import. Has anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Have you restarted VSCode? This sometimes helps...

Comment: Are you using the same python executable for installing and running? You might have 2 different versions of python.

Comment: restarting VS code after installing the packages with pip on cmd worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you restart VSCode after downloading your package. Sometimes, when you download a package while VSCode is still running, it doesn't recognize the package when using `import similaritymeasures`.

If that didn't work, then make sure that VSCode is using your preferred version of python. It is possible that you have more than one python version and it's using a non-compatible one to run your code. This can be done at the bottom right corner of the window by clicking the box that says: (for example) 3.9.5 64-bit. Then select a different (preferably older) version from the pop up widnow.

These are the solutions that came to my mind, I hope this helped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information like 'how to check which Python Version is used by VSCode'. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).